# Is Hagrid a half-blood?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

We know that Hagrid is half giant but was he considered a Muggle-born, half-blood, or a pure-blood? He just can't be a pure-blood but was his dad a wizard or a Muggle?

Comment: I dont know the lore.... Was his mother a wizard? Or a Miggle?

Comment: @Njohnny if Hagrid was half giant and his father was a (short) wizard, then there's a decent chance his mother is a...? :)